# How to create Vector robot eye animation with raspberry pi and SPI display?

Tags: python, graphics, raspberry-pi, lcd

I have a raspberry pi 4 (4GB) and a 2 inch Waveshare SPI LCD display. I’m trying to create animated eye expression just like the Vector Robot, but I have no clue on how to code the fluid animation (with acceptable frame rate). Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

Current attempt: I tried Waveshare’s python library with Python PIL, but the frame rate is extremely low…
Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my existing testing code, testmotion() basically moves a rectangle to the right 50 times within a for loop.
But it took almost 7 seconds to run....

```
import os
import sys
import time
import logging
import spidev as SPI
from lib import LCD_2inch
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

class CoreDisplay:
    # Raspberry pi pin configuration:
    RST = 27
    DC = 25
    BL = 18
    bus = 0
    device = 0

    def __init__(self):
        # Display with hardware SPI
        # DON'T CRERATE MULTIPLE DISPLAYER OBJECTS!!!
        self.disp = LCD_2inch.LCD_2inch()
        # initialize library
        self.disp.Init()
        # Clear display
        self.disp.clear() 

    def testmotion(self):
        # test to move a rectangle on screen
        x, y = 20, 20
        old_shape = [(x, y), (x + 40, y + 40)]
        for i in range(50): 
            # Cover the old shape in black
            image = Image.new("RGB", (self.disp.height, self.disp.width ), "BLACK")
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
            draw.rectangle(old_shape, fill ="Black")

            image = image.rotate(180)
            self.disp.ShowImage(image)

            # draw new shape
            shape = [(x, y), (x + 40, y + 40)]
            image = Image.new("RGB", (self.disp.height, self.disp.width ), "BLACK")
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
            draw.rectangle(shape, fill ="Cyan")

            image = image.rotate(180)
            self.disp.ShowImage(image)
            x += 1
            old_shape = shape

popDisplay = CoreDisplay()
popDisplay.testmotion()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what SPI clock speed do you use? try 30MHz if you can ... what rendering method you use? using LCD commands to render or passing framebuffer? If I see it right the LCD is 320x240 12/16/18 bpp so for 16bpp and 30MHz it should be  ~41ms per frame top speed so ~24.4140625 fps which should be enough... show code and relevant info

Comment: @Spektre, I just updated my code, not sure where to set the SPI clock speed, but when I run spidev.SpiDev(0,0).max_speed_hz it gives me 125000000. Not sure if this information is relevant...

Comment: @EvanZ I do not code in python nor for RPI (other users might be of help) the SPI clock is most likely set in the LCD lib itself. You render 2x50 frames in 7 sec -> ~14.28 fps that is fast enough for animation (so I do not think SPI is the problem) so if you want to speed up animation just increment the `x` by bigger number for example `x+=3;` the discrepancy between 24.4 and 14.28 fps might be different SPI clock and the rendering itself (you now SW rendering of image takes some time too and if the lib is coded poorly ... also python is one of the slowest languages out there)

Comment: the top of SPI clock can be found in the datasheed of RPIs CPU and the LCD itself use the smallest value amongs all the devices. However if you got too long or noisy cables you will need to use lower clock than HW capabilities max allowed speed. Too  high speed cause glitches in image or stop of working completely.